# Restart Notepad++ using NppExec

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

I develop a tool based on npp+nppexec and the limit of 40 scripts in menu is driving me mad.
The only solution I see is to have context menu items like "switch to X mode", "switch to Y mode" and so on. But is there a way to do it? Writing script that changes contextMenu.xml and NppExec.ini is good idea, but then I need to restart Notepad++ (for the changes to take effect) and maybe keep all opened tabs (not necessary). Is it possible? Or maybe there is an alternative to use instead of NppExec that does not have this limitation? Patching NppExec to make the limit higher is not an option.

Comment: Why not to consider SynWrite app, it has no limit for 40 scripts.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO]. Could you please be more specific? What exact steps you are doing in your tool? Which menu has 40 scripts limitation? It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.